# SQL server taking long time to execute query

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, query-performance

I am working from last 3 days on improve my sql server query. I have used `full text search` for searching huge database along with `limit` and `offset`. Check below is my query

```
declare @Offset int = 0,
        @Limit int = 20,
        @filters nvarchar(250) = null,
        @q nvarchar(50) = 'rice';


set @q = N'"'+@q+'*"';
select
     fa.alias_id
    ,fa.[allow_public]
    ,fa.[deleted]
    ,fa.[description]
    ,fa.[food_group_id]
    ,fa.alias_name
    ,fa.canonical_name
    ,fa.[model]
    ,fa.[source]
    ,fa.[region]
    ,fa.[UserId]
    --,fa.food_id
    ,fa.et_alias_id
from dbo.FoodAliasNames fa
--inner join dbo.Foods f
--on fa.food_id = f.Id
where contains((fa.alias_name,fa.canonical_name),@q) and fa.[source] = 'source1' --and fa.model in ('u','r')
order by fa.alias_id -- also here i want to sort by alias_name
offset @Offset rows
fetch next @Limit rows only;
```

When I run this query it took  min to complete. Please check below query execution plan. I have total **1313017** records in my table.

[image]

Below image for full text search execution plan

[image]

Below image is for clustered index scan on **FoodAliasNames**

[image]

How can I improve this query? Or Is there anything which I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an index on source and to make sure it is evaluated before the fulltext search so the fulltext search will be effectuated on a smaller subset.

To further improve performance you could create a table where you would store keywords and a many-to-many table connecting your table with the keywords table. Then you could search for keywords once for all the records to find out which keyword applied to which record and populate the many-to-many table. Finally, you would be able to check for having a record notifying that any of the keywords found in the search string in the many-to-many table as something done before the fulltext search.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you show some code to create index?

Comment: @Ajay of course. ```CREATE INDEX i1 ON FoodAliasNames (source);``` Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15